# Android: changing the location provider dynamically

Tags: android, geolocation, android-location

In my app, I need to get the location of my users. Since my app is going to do it constantly, I want to change the location provider in certain conditions (between GPS and NETWORK providers). My app is going to detect such conditions and change it.

But, I'm not sure how to change it dynamically.

So far, I have a thread (that, among other things, will check for these conditions) and I want it to change the location provider too. My code until now is as below:

```
public void run() {

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locationController = new LocationController();

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, time, desltaDistance, locationController );

    while (serviceIsRunning) {
        ...
        if (conditionsAreMet) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationController);
            if (provider == LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, time, desltaDistance, locationController );
            else
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, time, deltaDistance, locationController );
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

*The LocationController class implements LocationListener.

But, it don't seems to be the better way to do it. So, what I want to know is: there is a better way to change the location provider automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one answered this question, here is how I figured it out.

Instead of make the change between the providers, I registered a constant controller for the NETWORK_PROVIDER. And, according to my conditions, a controller for the GPS_PROVIDER may be registered or not.

It's easier to register/unregister the locations request for one provider, instead of keep changing between them.

Comment: Hi, could you please abbreviate on your answer a bit more, I struggle with a very similar task.

Comment: @Solx85, I did this two years ago in my old job hehe. I don't remember the code exactly, but I'll check in my documents if I can still find something. :)